# JFreeChart DomainAxis java2DToValue does not convert properly if plot has one TimeSeriesDataItem

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am trying to draw an XYLineAnnotation to plot.I am calculating length of line(lineLength parameter)after some operations.Although chartX and chartX + lineLength are different ,converted values are same(chartXx and chartYy).So line is not drawn on screen.Because start and end X coordinates are same.

I think I did not make any implementation that is dependent of items in plot.But code does work properly if plot has one TimeSeriesDataItem.I think for some cases it will plot so large lines. Maximum value of variable lineLength  is 18 pixel.So it must not draw so long lines.

```
    DateAxis domainAxis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
    RectangleEdge domainAxisEdge = plot.getDomainAxisEdge();
    Minute min = /** Minute presentation of only point in graph*/
    Double chartX = domainAxis.valueToJava2D(min.getFirstMillisecond(), subRect, domainAxisEdge);
    Double chartXx = domainAxis.java2DToValue(chartX, subRect, domainAxisEdge);
    Double chartYy = domainAxis.java2DToValue(chartX + lineLength, subRect, domainAxisEdge);
    XYLineAnnotation d = new XYLineAnnotation(chartXx, yValue, chartYy,
            yValue);
    futurePlot.addAnnotation(d);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Period type of TimeSeriesDataItem is Minute. I set this value as minimum range.Using min.next() function I obtained a new Period.Then I set Range of Domain.This solves my problem.
I reliazed that if only one point exist in plot, he does not recognize other data space values.